# Spring MVC bean creation error

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to make a spring mvc application with hibernate and mysql.

Without the hibernate part the project works and i get welcome page. but when i add the hibernate I get error in the service. Some autowiring proble I dont understand why it is happening

here is the github project url

```
https://github.com/ipvsazzad/SpringMVCHibernateSecuritySitemesh
```

when running this in the tomcat 7 server i am getting the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teamServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.lynas.service.impl.TeamServiceImpl.session; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/lynas/util/AppConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean com.lynas.util.AppConfig.sessionFactoryBean()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/lynas/util/AppConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource com.lynas.util.AppConfig.dataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.lynas.service.impl.TeamServiceImpl.session; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/lynas/util/AppConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean com.lynas.util.AppConfig.sessionFactoryBean()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/lynas/util/AppConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource com.lynas.util.AppConfig.dataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/lynas/util/AppConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean com.lynas.util.AppConfig.sessionFactoryBean()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/lynas/util/AppConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource com.lynas.util.AppConfig.dataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:527)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean com.lynas.util.AppConfig.sessionFactoryBean()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/lynas/util/AppConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource com.lynas.util.AppConfig.dataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/lynas/util/AppConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource com.lynas.util.AppConfig.dataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:324)
    at com.lynas.util.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f777301b.dataSource(<generated>)
    at com.lynas.util.AppConfig.sessionFactoryBean(AppConfig.java:47)
    at com.lynas.util.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f777301b.CGLIB$sessionFactoryBean$2(<generated>)
    at com.lynas.util.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f777301b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f81bf959.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at com.lynas.util.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f777301b.sessionFactoryBean(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource com.lynas.util.AppConfig.dataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool
    at com.lynas.util.AppConfig.dataSource(AppConfig.java:29)
    at com.lynas.util.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f777301b.CGLIB$dataSource$1(<generated>)
    at com.lynas.util.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f777301b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f81bf959.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at com.lynas.util.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f777301b.dataSource(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 71 more
Oct 22, 2014 10:18:30 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teamServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.lynas.service.impl.TeamServiceImpl.session; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/lynas/util/AppConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean com.lynas.util.AppConfig.sessionFactoryBean()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/lynas/util/AppConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource com.lynas.util.AppConfig.dataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
```

To me it seems like it cant find the hibernate.cfg.xml file. anyway How can fix this??

Comment: Have you actually read the stacktrace? The error is quite clear... `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool`. You are missing a required jar file. You are using a 11 year old snapshot version of commons-dbcp. Switch to an actual version like `1.4` or even better drop DBCP altogether and use something like  [HikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/) (i have had a lot of trouble with Commons DBCP).

Comment: I am not as good as you. anyway thanks for the HikariCP idea. could u tell me the alternate BasicDataSource in HikariCP

Comment: Check the documentation it is explained in there... Also it has nothing to do with being good in your work it has to do with reading a stacktrace...

Comment: exactly i am not that good in reading stack trace. I am new programmer. thanks for your help again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite clear if you look at the stacktrace.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 71 more
```

You are missing required classes.

Looking at your dependencies you are using an 11 year old snapshot version of commons-dbcp, instead of the most recent 1.4 version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>20030825.184428</version>
</dependency>
```

Change to use a newer version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Although commons-dbcp might work I wouldn't recommend it anymore. At least you should be using commons-dbcp2 which is activly maintained or something else like [HikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/). Remove the commons-dbcp dependency and add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP-java6</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Next in your code you need to add something like following to configure HikariCP as datasource.

```
@Bean
public BasicDataSource dataSource(){

    HikariDataSource ds= new HikariDataSource();
    ds.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
    ds.setUsername("root");
    ds.setPassword( "");
    ds.setDataSourceClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource");
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", "localhost");
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", "hibnatedb");
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", true);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", 250);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", 2048);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", true);
    return ds;
}
```

Regarding your hibernate configuration ideally this shouldn't exist or at least contain only the mapped classes. The properties you should move to java instead (and I suggest using another dialect).

```
private Properties hibernateProperties(){

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    properties.put("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider");             
    return properties;
}
```

Ideally you ditch the `hibernate.cfg.xml` and use the following java config instead.

```
@Bean
public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean(){

    AnnotationSessionFactoryBean asfb = new  AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
    asfb.setDataSource(dataSource());
    asfb.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    asfb.setPackagesToScan("com.lynas.model");
    return asfb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with one dependency. I used

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
     <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

where I should have used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring supports Hibernate3 as well as Hibernate4; your are using version 3 (`public org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` from your stacktrace) so if you want use Hibernate4 check around SO (or other resources over the net) about how to use Spring with Hibernate4.

Comment: I am using spring orm 4.1.1 which is the latest version. I contains hibernate 3 jar so I have to use hibernate 3 for the entity manager